Have os.system() or subprocess.call() without return or error
I'd like a way for os.system() or subprocess.call() not return ANY text in the terminal.
I want to have code running in the background that closes out of an application whenever it opens, and I already have that down
def x():
    os.system("code here")
    subprocess.call("code here")
x()

would return...
(code here) was executed successfully

How would I keep it from returning the error or output no matter what? I have it running in the background with threading but it doesn't make a difference either way.
I've tried this question's answers but they either don't work, or show the output still. I'm slightly limited on the things I can do since it is a company computer.

Redirect stdout and stderr by adding >/dev/null 2>&1 to the command line.

When using subprocess you can use the stdout=subprocess.NULL, stderr=subprocess.NULL arguments.

Where is "was executed successfully" coming from? That's not normally done by either function.

It was an example. I couldn't actually think of what output I should've put there. Should be pretty obvious.

@Barmar: It's subprocess.DEVNULL, not subprocess.NULL, but yes, that works. And TIL subprocess.call does in fact accept additional arguments to pass to Popen; I thought it was a one-trick pony with limited configurability, apparently I was off base.

With os.system(), you do it the same as how you would hide the output when running the command from a terminal. Seems like that should be obvious.

btw, you should be using subprocess.run not os.system or subprocess.call (the subprocess module is preferred, but call is deprecated in favor of run)
